# reactive ggplot tooltip error when nothing in UI selected,

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server, ggplotly

I have this reactive ggplot shiny example using tooltip,
problem is that when nothing selected, I got this error >
`Error : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, colour, label and group`
When I try this code without plottly and tooltip, then it is working fine.
Any idea how to fix this within ggplotly and tooltip ?
I posted both version of app.R

app.R  (ggplotly version with error when nothing selected)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    position='right',
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput("region_input", "Select Regions:", 
                  
                  choices = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"),
                  selected = "Alabama",
                  multiple = TRUE),
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("distPlot"),
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"), class = "factor"), 
                         date = structure(c(18283, 18284, 18285, 18283, 18284, 18285,18283, 18284, 18285), class = "Date"), 
                         confirmed = c(5L,10L, 7L, 20L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 40L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
  
  filtered_data <- reactive( {
    
    
    filtered_data <- data %>%
      filter(Region %in% input$region_input)
    return(filtered_data)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed, label = Region, color = Region, group = Region, text=paste(date, "\n" , Region, " " ,confirmed  ))) +
        geom_line( aes(date, confirmed, color = Region)),
        tooltip = ("text")
    ) 
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

app.R working version with ggplot only,without tooltip

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    position='right',
    sidebarPanel(
      
      h4(selectInput("region_input", "Select Regions:", 
                     
                     choices = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"),
                      selected = "Alabama",
                     multiple = TRUE),
         
      )),
    mainPanel(
      
      
      
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
   
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"), class = "factor"), 
                         date = structure(c(18283, 18284, 18285, 18283, 18284, 18285,18283, 18284, 18285), class = "Date"), 
                         confirmed = c(5L,10L, 7L, 20L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 40L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
  
    filtered_data <- reactive( {
      filtered_data <- data %>%
      filter(Region %in% input$region_input)
    return(filtered_data)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed, label = Region, color = Region, group = Region)) +
      geom_line( aes(date, confirmed, color = Region))

  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Dataframe>

```
> data
   Region       date confirmed
1 Alabama 2020-01-22         5
2 Alabama 2020-01-23        10
3 Alabama 2020-01-24         7
4  Alaska 2020-01-22        20
5  Alaska 2020-01-23         4
6  Alaska 2020-01-24         1
7 Arizona 2020-01-22         3
8 Arizona 2020-01-23        40
9 Arizona 2020-01-24         8
```

added screenshot error [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for NULL when nothing is selected.  Try this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"), class = "factor"), 
                         date = structure(c(18283, 18284, 18285, 18283, 18284, 18285,18283, 18284, 18285), class = "Date"), 
                         confirmed = c(5L,10L, 7L, 20L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 40L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
  
  filtered_data <- reactive( {
    if (is.null(input$region_input)) {
      filtered_data <- NULL
    }else {
      filtered_data <- data %>%
        filter(Region %in% input$region_input)
    }
    
    return(filtered_data)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(filtered_data())) {
      ggplotly(
        ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed, label = Region, color = Region, group = Region, text=paste(date, "\n" , Region, " " ,confirmed  ))) +
          geom_line( aes(date, confirmed, color = Region)),
        tooltip = ("text")
      ) 
    }else return(NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip is working fine here.

[image]

I rearranged your code a bit.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput("region_input", "Select Regions:", 
                  
                  choices = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"),
                  selected = "Alabama",
                  multiple = TRUE)
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("distPlot")
    ) ,  position='right')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"), class = "factor"), 
                         date = structure(c(18283, 18284, 18285, 18283, 18284, 18285,18283, 18284, 18285), class = "Date"), 
                         confirmed = c(5L,10L, 7L, 20L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 40L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
  
  filtered_data <- reactive( {
    
    if (length(input$region_input) > 0){
    filtered_data <- data %>%
      filter(Region %in% input$region_input)
    return(filtered_data)}
    else{
      return(data)
    }
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = date, y = confirmed, label = Region, color = Region, group = Region, text=paste(date, "\n" , Region, " " ,confirmed  ))) +
        geom_line( aes(date, confirmed, color = Region)),
      tooltip = ("text")
    ) 
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is now working with no choices as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Are you sure ? me not working when nothing selected, I see you have one selected.

Comment: When nothing is selected, the ggplot 2 will fail because the aes arguments are not of same length .. that is because the region_input is empty and the filtered_data is empty. Changed my answer

Comment: Thanks Amit now is working also your version. However  I will use YBS solution. Anyway you  said that "ggplot 2 will fail because the aes arguments are not of same length..." but when you check my 2nd version app with ggplot only.. this works fine also without any error handling...So seems that issue is with tooltip...somewhere.